# How do I find a mapping f : X -> Y to characterize the relationship between 2 time-series X and Y?

Tags: time-series, python, function, decomposition

I have a time series Y, and another time series X related to Y.

The value of Y is affected by X and some noise.

How can I separate the effect of X on Y ?

That is, how do I find a mapping f : X -> Y to characterize the relationship between X and Y ?

Here is the figure illustration of X and Y:

[image]

Comment: Could you tell us more about the data? I'm afraid that "finding the $f: X \to Y$ mapping" would fit all the machine learning and statistical models. The answer would be "use some machine learning/statistical/time-series model". It's too broad unless you can make the problem more focused.

Comment: Plotting $Y$ vs $X$ would be a good place to start; from your plots it isn't obvious what relationship there is between $X$ and $Y$. This would start to clarify the problem